# mysql v5.5 index performance

Tags: mysql, performance, index

On a 5.5.23 server (that needs to go to 5.7 at least, I know) I have an InnoDB table with 3 columns (there are a few more that are not relevant here):

```
TimeC (bigint, unix timestamp)
id (integer)
value (integer).
```

The table currently has an index on  `id`. The table contains ~15mil rows. The three columns above all allow NULL values (I suspect that's a first clue here).

The query in question is like this:

```
select id, sum(value) as TotalV
from table_name
where timeC >=154013600000  and timeC < 1540742400000
group by id
order by TotalV desc;
```

This query takes about 280sec on our server.

I decided to add an index on the date-related column `TimeC`.

The query now takes about 260sec, i.e. the improvement is very small.

The "explain" utility shows,  without the new index:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
table: TableName
type: index
possible_keys: NULL
key: TableName_CC_IDX
key_len: 768
ref: NULL
rows: 14830632
Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

...and WITH the new index:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
table: TableName
type: range
possible_keys: TableName_TimeC
key: TableName_TimeC
key_len: 9
ref: NULL
rows: 540694
Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

So my question is, why is it not using BOTH indexes in the latter case when both indexes exist and when both are relevant to the specific query? Generally, what could I do to speed up this query?

(from Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (
    id varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    timeC bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    value decimal(42,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY TableName (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

mysql> show indexes from TableName\G
        Table: TableName
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: TableName_CC_IDX
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 29
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: Index_comment:
```

Comment: *why is it not using BOTH indexes* Only one index can be used.

Comment: *key: TableName_CC_IDX key_len: 768* It seems it's not *an index on `id`*... too long.

Comment: @Akina : `show indexes` tells me that the `TableName_CC_IDX` index is a B-tree index on `id`.

Comment: *`show indexes` tells me that* It tells for you ONLY. Nobody else see it.

Comment: PS. Index by one filed of INTEGER type must have length of 4 or 5 (dependent by is the field nullable) both for BTREE and HASH types. Not 768...

Comment: @Akina Here it is for YOU to see: `mysql> show indexes from TableName\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: TableName
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: TableName_CC_IDX
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 29
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
`

Comment: Please edit the info about table structure in your Q from abstract 3-columns list to SHOW CREATE TABLE output (maybe skipping unnesessary fields and extra, but keeping the info about indices mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

You need a multicolumn index `(id, timeC, value)` or `(timeC, id, value)` because existing `timeC` and defailt `id` indexes are not sufficient.

The common rule is to create the index containing all the columns used by JOIN, GROUP BY, ORDER BY and WHERE clauses. The order columns should be listed in the index can vary due to the exact queries, columns cardinality and even the amount of data.

Comment: For more details on what columns to put in what order:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

The time change (280->260) is probably not significant but reflects what might be cached in RAM.

*If* that time range is a 'small' fraction of the total, then `INDEX(timeC, id, value)` should help -- because fewer rows would need to be touched, and the index is "covering".  Please add that index and provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

The `GROUP BY one-thing ORDER BY another-thing` will necessitate at least one "filesort".

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

There may actually be an optimization improvement in 5.7 that a particular index could take advantage of.

Reach about [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) as a possible solution to performance.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There is *no way* what you presented to us could lead to key_length=768.  That smells like `VARCHAR(255) NULL CHARACTER SET utf8`.

**The table**

Before we can fix the indexing, let's try to do some fixes to the table.

(Caution: The suggested SELECTs, below, will take a lengthy table scan.)

- `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(id));`, then consider lowering the `255` to some value not too much bigger than that max.
- `154013600000` - Are you using Java?  Do you need the milliseconds?  `BIGINT SIGNED` is 8 bytes; `INT UNSIGNED` is 4 bytes.
- `DECIMAL(42,2)` occupies 20 bytes.  `SELECT MAX(ABS(value))` and consider shrinking the size.  Or consider `FLOAT` (4 bytes).
- All `NULL`?  `SELECT SUM(id IS NULL), SUM(timeC is NULL), SUM(value IS NULL)` to see if you actually have any nulls.
- `SELECT id, timeC, value, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM t GROUP BY id, timeC, value ORDER BY ct DESC LIMIT 5;`  -- to see if you have any dups and what some of them are.  If no dups, then one of the proposed indexes could be `PRIMARY KEY`, which is essentially 'free' in InnoDB.
- "there are a few more that are not relevant here" -- Check the other columns for excessive size.

Let's try to get a PK added and the columns shrunken *before* continuing the `INDEX` discussion.

My comments apply to both 5.5 and 5.7.  (`TIMESTAMP(3)`, which I did not bring up, is not available until 5.6.)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `TableName` (
  `id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeC` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(42,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `TableName` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8    ID represents a cell phone number but it's modeled as varchar(255)

Comment: I have innodb buffer size = 1GB. I'm reluctant to add the (large) triple column index because I don't want to delay the numerous inserts on it for the sake of speeding up a single query that runs occasionally.

Comment: For testing purposes and to satisfy my curiosity I added the triple column index (on timeC, id and value, in that order) and confirmed that it's used in the query using "explain". Now the query takes 277sec, so the gain in negligible.

Comment: @GID - Let's tackle the table; it may be twice as bulky as needed.  See additions to my Answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Yes we need the milliseconds and use Java. The `value` column is already `decimal(42,2)`.  There are no NULLs in those three columns, and the cellphone number is, of course, never longer than  16 characters, but the DB has been designed years ago in my absence by Java developers and cannot really change structure, I'm afraid, as it is in production. How much impact does the 256-size of the ID have, though? There is one more column `varchar(2048)` that also has excessive length.

Comment: @GID - There is no simple answer to "how much impact".  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big (in GB) is the table?  Are there other queries hitting the table?  What percent of the table does this query hit?  The big solution may be to build and maintain a [_Summary table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).